# Is it possible to have the import done only for specific python versions?

Tags: python, import

I implemented a class in `file.py`.

`file.py` is imported in `another_file.py`. `another_file.py` has bazel testing for `python2`, but `file.py` is only supported for `python3`+. So I don't need to import `file.py` for `python2` executions.

Is there a way to have the import done for specific python versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys` to check the versions of `python`:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 3: # Python 3
    # [import python3 dependent packages here]
else: # Python 2
    # [import python2 dependent packages here]

""" rest of your code """
```

Comment: does `sys.version_info[0] == 3` include all 3.X versions or just 3.0?

Comment: This is what `sys.version_info` returns for my installation: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`. So when we do this `sys.version_info[0]` we are returning the `major` field which is `3`. That would allow all `3.X` versions.

Comment: @dzdang, if this answered your question, I would appreciate if you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **six** library.

```
import six

if six.PY2:
  # import python 2 library
else:
  # import python 3 library
```